# Is it possible to query the majority value or distinct?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to get unique values using distinct and group concat?

```
    +------------------------+
    |       Symbol           | 
    +------------------------+
    |        1_ABC           |  
    |        2_ABC           |  
    |        3_ABC           |  
    |        ABC_4           |  
    |        ABC_5           |  
    +------------------------+
```

This is my query:

```
     GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(Symbol) SEPARATOR ', ') 
as Symbol, count(distinct(Symbol)) as total 
from mytable;
```

This is my output:-

```
        +----------------------------------+------+
        |              Symbol              | total|
        +----------------------------------+------+
        |1_ABC, 2_ABC, 3_ABC, ABC_4, ABC_5 |   5  |
        +----------------------------------+------+
```

And my expected output is this:

```
    +----------------------------------+------+
    |              Symbol              | total|
    +----------------------------------+------+
    |               ABC                |   1  |
    +----------------------------------+------+
```

Any suggestion and help will appreciate, thanks

Comment: short answer - no, sql does not work with "similar" values or fuzzy logic, only with exact match

Comment: so i might go for long method? using like DISTINCT RIGHT(symbol, 4) or distinct from left, or update them if contains _ from left or right? or maybe you have a much more better idea?